# How to share to whatsapp from website

Tags: web, share, webclient, whatsapp

I'm developing a website from where I would like to have a functionality that would allow me to share the content from the website to my contacts in whatsapp.

Does anyone know if there's a way to do that? There's already a web version of whatsapp that you can hook up to from your PC or laptop, so I think it would be logical if there was some kind of a way to share to there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a link what `whatsapp` protocol, something like below

`whatsapp://send?text=Programmatically%20change%20Taskbar%20icon%20in%20WPF http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dignaj.com%2Fchange-taskbar-icon-in-wpf%2F`

Comment: Can you please clarify what does whatsapp protocol do? I mean what will happen after people press that link? Does Whatsapp application need to be installed on a computer prior to that or will whatsapp web-client open?

Comment: thanks to explain your answer, Stackoverflow target fully and understandable answer, thanks